# Conditional registering a command decorator based on generic type constraints in SimpleInjector

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, decorator, simple-injector

How to register a **conditional decorator** in `SimpleInjector`? Here are my definitions:

```cs
public interface ICommand { }

public interface ICleanableCommand : ICommand {
    void Clean();
}

public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> 
    where TCommand : ICommand {
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public class CleanableCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> 
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand> 
    where TCommand : ICleanableCommand {

    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _handler;

    public CleanableCommandHandlerDecorator(
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> handler) {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    void ICommandHandler<TCommand>.Handle(TCommand command) {
        command.Clean();
        _handler.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

And I'm trying:

```cs
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    );

container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(CleanableCommandHandlerDecorator<>)
    // ,context => context.ImplementationType ???
    // I want to register this decorator for commandhandlers 
    // which their command implements ICleanableCommand 
    );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `RegisterDecorator` overload that takes an `DecoratorPredicateContext` to define the condition under which your decorator should be applied. However, since in your case the condition is just the generic type constraint, you don't have to supply a predicate. Simple Injector will automatically ignore the decorator when the given service type is not decoratable, and this includes generic type constraints.

In other words, just register your decorator as follows and it will work correctly:

```cs
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(CleanableCommandHandlerDecorator<>));
```

Comment: Really?! It's so nice and useful. Thank you. Cheer

Answer (score 2):

It seems I can use **`DecoratorPredicateContext.ServiceType`**:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(CleanableCommandHandlerDecorator<>),
    context => {
        var genArg = context.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        return typeof(ICleanableCommand).IsAssignableFrom(genArg);
    });
```